# Opening the VF page in a new Tab Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, visualforce-component, button

We are converting a VF Page from Classic to Lightning and this VF page called from the button in Classic is like
[image]

So when the button is clicked in Classic it opens the VF page in a new pop up window. I tried converting the VF page to lightning compatible but the issue is the VF Page opens in the same page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Op_Pg_Ext" id="page" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true" >
 <apex:form id="form">
 .......
```

How can I approach to resolve the issue, I am new to lightning and any suggestion helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer your request as the best solution depends on your VFP (Visualforce page)'s job.

Here are some quick suggestions:

A 1st solution is creating a new quick action on Opportunity object with an action type "Custom Visualforce"

- pros: quick and easy-to-implement solution
- cons: VFP displayed in a modal, width fixed, not very handy.

The 2nd solution is embedding your VFP in a standard Lightning Component and make it available on your Lightning record page.

- pros: Easy to do with the Lightning App Builder (click & point). That way, your VFP will be directly accessible on your record page without clicking on a button
- cons: Looks like your VFP is a form, might overload your record page

Finally, my 3rd and last suggestion, developing 2 very simple lightning components :

1. 1st containing a simple button which will open the 2nd component in a new browser tab
2. 2nd embedding your VFP

   - pros: behaviour quite enough close to what asked
   - cons: need to have a small lightning component development skill

I hope you find something that fits your need !

---

EDIT: Here are some samples for the 3rd solution.

myButton.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:button label="Base" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
</aura:component>
```

myButtonController.js

```
({
    handleClick : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
           componentDef : "c:myAuraVFPContainer",
           componentAttributes: {
              vfpName : 'myVisualforcePageName'
           }
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
});
```

myAuraVFPContainer.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name='vfpName' type='String'/>
    <iframe src="{!https://yourdomainroot.salesforce.com/apex/ + v.vfpName}" width="100%" height="500px;" frameBorder="0"/>
</aura:component>
```

Do not forget to replace variables like *myVisualforcePageName* and *yourdomainroot* in the code.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer.. Yes I tried Quick Action, as you said I couldnt change the size of the Page. Can you please share any samples for the third option?

Comment: Yes sure, please have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and I get the error .. I posted it as a new question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289194/opening-a-vf-page-in-new-window-in-using-lightning-component here.. Can you please take a look at it and say what am I missing.